# Email confirmation link fail in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a confirmation system using email link and tokens using Django

here are my files :

**tokens.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six
class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +
            six.text_type(user.is_active)
        )
account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
```

That is where I've created the token

**Forms.py**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, help_text='Must be a valid E-mail')
    user_name = forms.CharField(required=True, help_text='')
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text='')
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text='Password confirmation')
    avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'user_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'avatar')
        labels = {
            'user_name': 'user_name',
            'email': ' email',
            'password1': 'password1',
            'password2': 'password2',
            'avatar': 'avatar',
        }

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        return data.lower()
```

That is where I've created the signup form

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    current_user_ip = get_client_ip(request)
    current_temp = Temp.objects.filter(created_by_ip=current_user_ip)
    current_temp.delete()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        signup_form = SignUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if signup_form.is_valid():
            user = signup_form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_confirmed = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your Jehlum account.'
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
    else:
        signup_form = SignUpForm()

    context = {
        'signup_form': signup_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

Here  is where I've created the views of both signing up and the activation view

**acc_active_email.html**

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},
Please click on the link to confirm your registration,
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

that is the template for the email that's is being sent.

and finally here are my **urls.py**

```
path('signup/', web_site_views.signup, name='signup'),
path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', web_site_views.activate, name='activate'),
```

It says (Activation link is invailed) everytime i try to use it . so the steps works fine and i revice the email with a link but when i click the link it gives me the invailed link error !

Comment: in activate function what is failing? Are you not able to get the user using uidb64 or is the check_token function failing?

Comment: @serbia99 I think the link structure is what fails. it generates a link this way `/%5Eactivate/(%3FPb'MjM'%5B0-9A-Za-z_%5C-%5D+)/(%3FP4y5-bd24d91d46f0f28d8198%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,13%7D-%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,20%7D)/$`

Comment: If link does not match then the view function will not be called. But you are getting "Activation link is invalid" as response, which means that the view function is being called, therefore the url is proper.

Comment: @serbia99 yes, make sense .. but I can't find out what really fails inside the function!

Comment: @serbia99 any help or suggestion for how to find out the missing part in the function?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, did you ever resolve it?